# removing certain form fields upon submit

Tags: jquery

When my ajax form submits i will have some select menus that will submit with a "0" value.
I'd like to remove those selects along with it's paired input (which contains an id) from the submission.

I'm not sure how i would go about achieving this.

Here's a sample of the html source.  There are only 3 in this sample, but there could be many more or less.

```
<select id="customer_orders_attributes_0_quantity" name="customer[orders_attributes][0][quantity]">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input id="customer_orders_attributes_0_product_id" name="customer[orders_attributes][0][product_id]" type="hidden" value="917">

<select id="customer_orders_attributes_1_quantity" name="customer[orders_attributes][1][quantity]">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input id="customer_orders_attributes_1_product_id" name="customer[orders_attributes][1][product_id]" type="hidden" value="918">

<select id="customer_orders_attributes_2_quantity" name="customer[orders_attributes][2][quantity]">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input id="customer_orders_attributes_2_product_id" name="customer[orders_attributes][2][product_id]" type="hidden" value="919">
```

so if customer_orders_attributes_0_quantity and customer_orders_attributes_2_quantity happened to be 0 - how can i tell it to drop it before the form submits along with it's matching _product_id input.

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512357/how-to-hide-html-form-select-option this may help

Comment: thank you but i think this only hides them?   im looking to actually remove them so the do not get submitted at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//remove inputs following any select lists with option 0 selected
$('option[value="0"]:selected').parent().next('input').remove();

//remove select lists with option 0 selected
$('option[value="0"]:selected').parent().remove();
```

Comment: thank you. but how would one go about removing it' paired input field?

Comment: you want to remove the whole list?

Comment: im sorry. not following exactly.   when i have one of those selects with an option 1 selected and then run $('option[value="0"]').parent().remove(); in console. it removes all the select menus.

when i refresh the page and try again with one of the option 1's selected and execute this in console $('option[value="0"]').parent().next('input').remove();  it removes all of the inputs.

Comment: ok so then you just want the ones removed that have option 0 selected? I thought you meant if they had an option 0 at all. I edited again. It should now work how you want it.