# jQuery display none a option in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display none a option of a form.

HTML:

```
<option class="level-0" value="top-10-villen-de">Top-10-Villen</option>
```

jQuery:

```
if(jQuery('option').attr('value') == 'top-10-villen-de'){
    jQuery(this).css('display', 'none');
}
```

I've a issue in my if statement but I can't figure out where is my issue.

Can somebody helps me?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just add the `display:none` to your class in CSS?

Comment: Hiding an option element is nor cross browser compatible

Comment: alternates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512357/how-to-hide-html-form-select-option

Comment: @Arun P Johny - Especially in Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiding the dropdown option isn't compatible with all browser.

I've got a better option.
`wrap` the option into span and when you need it back `unwrap` it

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/xms2uydx/

Comment: Thanks for the information about compatiblity with the browsers.
You jsfiddle works fine. Have a nice day.

Comment: @cgee: dont seem to work for me. also wrapping option element in span results in invalid html.

Answer (score 1):

You are  using wrong **this** see this example for **THIS** Scope

http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/r2m2ucgv/2/

The above example is give you difference between two this.
1. which is out of Jquery. 
2. which is inside jquery function.

1. so as you can see in example first console **i.e console.log(this)** will return window object.

2 . $(this) which is inside click function will give you different value it is related to your button it will gives you button scope

you can also use

**jQuery('option').find('.level-0').css('display', 'none')**
if you know the class of option.

**HTML**

---

```
<button>option 1</button>
<button>option 2</button>
<select>
    <option class="level-0" value="top-10-villen-de">Top-10-Villen</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="top-1">Top-20</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

---

```
console.log(this)
$('button').click(function () {

    if ($(this).text() === "option 1") {
        if (jQuery('option').attr('value') == 'top-10-villen-de') {
            console.log('inside')
            console.log(jQuery('option[class="level-0"]'))
            jQuery('option[class="level-0"]').css('display', 'none');
        }

    } else {

        jQuery('option[class="level-0"]').toggle()
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because context `this` in if statement do not refer to option element.Correct way to achieve this would be to find element with attribute value equal to `top-10-villen-de` along with `.hide()`:

```
jQuery('option[value="top-10-villen-de"]').hide();
```

FYI, the hiding of option elements do not work. a good workaround for this would be to disable the option by setting its disabled property to true.

Comment: You very well know its not cross browser compatible as I have seen in your previous answer, then  why did you not incorporated it.

Comment: @Satpal: oh i remember. but people are hardly taking IE compatibility in consideration nowadays. ill still update the answer with alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery , whenever you have more than one element in DOM , then to access all elements you have to use `$('selector').each(function(index,Obj){})`.

Use this code to hide the options you want

```
$('#temp').find('option').each(function(index,Obj){
if($(this).attr('value')=='2')
$(this).css('display', 'none');
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/uk29Lsbp/)**

Answer (score -2):

You can set display none when it the value is `top-10-villen-de`

```
jQuery( "select" ).change(function() {
  if(jQuery(this).val() == 'top-10-villen-de'){
    jQuery(this).find("option[value='top-10-villen-de']").css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Here the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/jva8ju1s/

Comment: This would hide the whole `select`.